# Webpack Externals doesn't seem to work for React

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm creating a React Library, already published it to `npm` somehow. But, I faced several issues/questions during the development flow.

#### Summary of My Code:

**1) package.json** (Showing only relevant stuff)

Notice that `react` is present in both `peerDependencies` and `devDependencies`. My library doesn't even need `react` for `development`, but some package that I'm using depends on it hence it's there in `devDependencies`.

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0"
     ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
     ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0"
    ...
  }
```

**2) webpack.config.json**

I have mentioned in the externals, that webpack should not include `react` in the built bundle, and instead rely on `react` to be present in the consumer's environment.
However, this is not working as I have imported react in one of my library code (`import react from 'react';`) and hence it get's put into the bundle. **I can say that because I'm getting the multiple react version error for hooks**.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'react-flexible-sliding-menu',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    // Use external version of React
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
      umd: 'react'
    },
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom',
      umd: 'react-dom'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Unless I am wrong, I dont think react will even be there in your devdeps if you havent installed it. But as to why its still in the built bundle, I'm not sure.

Comment: @SreeramPadmanabhan Even I was a bit confused, but then I did some digging and found out it's getting installed because of `docz`.